# SOLR many to many with extra column map

Tags: solr

Is it possible to store many to many relation with extra column?

This is a situation:

stock_item solr core is core that contains everything about stock item (so name, price, description, ...).

and its taken from stock_item entity. That entity has (aside of other properties that are not important in this question) many to many relation with extra column with stock_item_group entity. Stock item group is entity for storing some stock_item together (so there could be for example "easter" stock item group that contains only stock items that have something in common with easter).
Simple many to many relation is easy to insert into solr (there will be property on stock_item core holding list of stock_item_group ids). But, there is that extra column. That column represents order of stock item in stock_item_group (so easter bunny would be first, easter egg seconds, ...).

I have no clue how to insert that into solr (is it possible to store array of map  into stock_item core?)

The wnated behavioral is query, where I specify just the stock_item_group id and solr returns list of stock_items ordered by that extra column.

Comment: I have a hard time parsing what you're really after in your question. Usually you'll have to structure your documents around a specific item, such as stock item, and then enrich it with data from your many-to-many-links per document, but it's hard to say without a good understanding of your actual problem.

Comment: What part of my problem is unclear, I can modify question. I have M:N (two entities) I connect with additional information (order in which are they connected together). On a M entity I have a solr core (so I can query on it, get that etc.). Without relation I would just save array of ids of N entity on which is that item connected. Then I would just query on that M core telling I want records of this core that have some id of N entity saved. That would be pretty easy. But I have that additional order column. So I gotta say, give me all cores records ordered by that additional column (its int).

Comment: The whole paragraph that explains the issue should be clarified. Add examples of how it looks in your db, and examples of what the query should answer. Initial guess is that you can use a dynamic field name for ordering, but it's hard to say without understanding the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are tracking (group) presence and sort order. If the number of stock items groups is not too high, you could have two dynamic field patterns defined:

- group_included_[id] (as boolean)
- group_order_[id] (as int)

And then you just filter on included and sort on order. You could also have included as usual multivalue field if you prefer. You could even skip it and just check for presence of any value in group_order_[id] field, but the performance will be worse.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Makes sense to me. But I' figurred out another aproach. What if I create another core for Stock itemgroup. That group would hold list of stock item ids ordered by that order. I aint sure if I can connect from that new core to stack item core. So if I ask solr on stock item group, it will return ordered list of stock item cores. Is that possible? And if it does, which approach has better performance?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your alternative solution. SO is not the best place to have a deep discussion on alternatives. Solr users Mailing list may be better for that.

Comment: We implemented that (kinda) your way. We have used one dynamic field holding order value in group (we tried to use 2 columns but performance diff wasnt that significant in our case so we decided to use just one field). Thak you for your advice.